# Scala assign type a dynamic value

Tags: scala, dynamic, typing

I'm pretty new to Scala and I'm wondering if it is possible to create a type dynamically in some way. In practice what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
trait BaseAB
case class A(value: String) extends BaseAB
case class B(value: String) extends BaseAB

def build(name: String, m: String): BaseAB = {
  type t = name match {
    case "A" => A
    base "B" => B
  }
  new t(m)
}
```

Comment: you might also want to look at [generics](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create new instances in you case clauses, like

```
case "A" => A(m)
case "B" => B(m)
```

or you can create partially applied function representing constructor and then provide value

```
def build(name: String, m: String): BaseAB = {
  val construct = name match {
    case "A" => A.apply _
    case "B" => B.apply _
  }
  construct(m)
} 

> build("A", "boo") 
res25: BaseAB = A("boo")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works almost as-is, but it's not because there is some sort of "type-valued runtime-defined variables". Instead, it works because there are companion objects called `A` and `B` that have methods `apply(s: String): A` and `apply(s: String): B`, and also both conform to type `String => BaseAB`:

```
trait BaseAB
case class A(value: String) extends BaseAB
case class B(value: String) extends BaseAB

def build(name: String, m: String): BaseAB = {
  val t = name match {
    case "A" => A
    case "B" => B
  }
  t(m)
}
```

In this code snippet, the type of `t` is inferred to be `String => BaseAB` (possibly with some additional marker traits like `Serializable`).

If you are sure that there are only `"A"` and `"B"`, you can also write it as

```
  (if (name == "A") A else B)(m)
```

it works for the same reason.